# Is there an alternative to f.lux which runs constantly?

Tags: 12.04

F.lux is an application that adapts the color of your screen to the time of day such that the screen is redder during the night (i.e. it serves the same function as computer glasses). I want to keep the filter running constantly, but the linux version does not allow this. Are there any other alternatives which do? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Youngin  I had tried f.lux with no success , then i found redshift in software center . It autostart during boot system and apply as far as you keep your machine running.